# Going back in the Edit Review Queue doesn't close Rejection dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits, user-interface

When I want to reject a suggested edit in the review queue as usual I open the dialog showing the rejection options. Now if I go back in the browser history the previous suggested edit shows up, but the rejection dialog is still open. If I then submit the rejection, it applies to the previous, currently showing suggested edit<sup>[1]</sup>.

This is somewhat problematic, because I had accidentally hit the back button on my mouse and didn't notice that I went back to the previous edit, since the post body is hidden behind the dialog. Then I submitted the rejection and effectively rejected the wrong edit.

<sub>1: Only happens when I skipped the edit. I get an error if I have reviewed it before, since I cannot vote twice.</sub>

Comment: Exactly the same thing just happened to me. As I result I ended up rejecting [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22343852) with the reject reason from the previous (i.e. next) page. Luckily I'd have rejected it anyway, but my comment makes no sense in the context of that suggested edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better late than never...

Starting with the next build, we'll be closing open popups when going back or forward within a review queue.